# Why using multithreading so slow when reading file with tons of lines?

Tags: python, multithreading, file

I'm reading a file with tons of lines in it and want to compare one line with the rest of the lines step by step.

and when condition met, store value in the variable 'result' and print it after all thread stop

However, when I don't use thread it takes about 0.1 seconds but when I use 10 thread it takes more than 0.5 seconds.

Why using multi-thread take more time than one thread?

here is a sample code I wrote

```
import threading

result = []


def get_match(file):
    outer_lines = file.readlines()
    inner_lines = file.readlines()
    for f1 in outer_lines:
        for f2 in inner_lines:
            print('compare file line by line')
            print('store int into global result variable')


def do(thread_count=10):
    threads = []
    with open('file.txt') as file:

        for t in range(thread_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target=get_match, args=(file,))
            threads.append(t)

        for t in threads:
            t.start()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()

    print(result)

do(10)
```

Comment: All threads are doing the same thing, meaning at 10 threads you have 10 times the work!

Comment: Do consider the GIL. I do think multiprocessing would be a better option...

Answer (score 1):

It's slower because each of your threads iterates over the whole file, basically you are doing the same thing 10 times.
You need to first split the file into 10 parts and then each one of them to separate threads